# No Updates possible with replicated database and updating via tableadapter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I'm maintaining an old application. I'd to start a merge replication between two servers.
But afterwards I get these error messages "*Updating columns with the rowguidcol property is not allowed*."

Is there really no way to use the tableadapters for updating anymore? Do I have to refactor this application in order to be able to do a merge replication?

Thanks for input.

**Edit**

I've checked the automatic generated XSD files and discovered that the in each updatestatement every field is updated. Some columns are from type unique-identifier and even if you cannot change these values from the application the statement goes like that

```
update myTable set uniquekeycol = oldValue .... where actualPrimaryKey = value
```

our testdatabase has the same scheme but is running on sql2008 and it looks like the application is working without any changes. (i've just created a merge replication without any subscribers).

it's getting stranger and stranger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replication adds triggers to the tables to capture changes and those triggers prevent the update of the replication id column (the one with the rowguidcol property). [Considerations for Merge Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151206.aspx):

> **Addition of uniqueidentifier Column**
>
> Merge replication uses a globally
>   unique identifier (GUID) column to
>   identify each row during the merge
>   replication process. If a published
>   table does not have a uniqueidentifier
>   column with the ROWGUIDCOL property
>   and a unique index, replication adds
>   one. Ensure that any SELECT and INSERT
>   statements that reference published
>   tables use column lists. If a table is
>   no longer published and replication
>   added the column, the column is
>   removed; if the column already
>   existed, it is not removed.

You're going to have to edit your dataset and remove the replication column from the projection list of your table adapters.